# Socialite Auth: How do I include more than one redirect uri for each service?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Or how can i dynamically set the redirect uri? I'm constantly having to solve merge conflicts because my local and production server use different redirects. Or maybe I should add services.php to gitignore?

my service.php

```
'google' =>[
    'client_id'=> env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' =>'http://localhost:3000/login/google/callback', 
],
```

I want to include a uri for production like

```
http://example.com/login/google/callback
```

I've tried using an array which didn't work

Comment: Have you tried using `'redirect' => url('login/google/callback'),`? This would set the URI correctly depending on whether you were running on production or locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set this dynamically with `url()`. This way it would update appropriately on any environment.

In your case it would look like this:

```
'google' =>[
    'client_id'=> env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => url('login/google/callback'), 
],
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set relative path instead of url() function. Socialite automatically add full url while requesting. Check below note

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite
If the redirect option contains a relative path, it will automatically be resolved to a fully qualified URL.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use url() in config files. It conflicts with PHP artisan. 
Just need to add all your callback URL to Google Developers Console

```
http://localhost:3000/login/google/callback
http://example.com/login/google/callback
```